# Remove HTML child inside its parent

Tags: python, regex

I have some HTML like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li><br>
  <li>Item 2</li><br>
  <li>Item 3</li><br>
</ul>

<img src="someImage.png"><br>
```

And I would like to remove the `<br>` tags from after the `<li>` tags and the `<img>` tags using regex though I'm not sure how to go about this. The HTML does not remain the same, so the image and lists may be in a different location or there may be other content though there will always be a `<br>` after a `</li>` and `</img>`

What regex could I use to solve this with python? Thanks.

**Edit:**

I tried using this `(<img.+?>)<br>` for the image but it did not work.

I don't want to just simply remove ALL of the `<br>` tags because there may be some useful ones in the HTML, rather I would like to have the ones after the list items and images removed.

Comment: can you post the code that your have tried so far?

Comment: @acutesoftware just done it.

Comment: Is `br` always the next sibling after the `img` and `li` tags?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the way to remove the `<br>` from the lists:

```
re.sub(r'</li>(\<br>)', '\1', string)
```

And for the images is just the same.

```
re.sub(r'(<img.+?>)(\<br>)', '\1', string)
```

Comment: Have you tested these?

Comment: this `re.sub(r'</li>(\<br>)', '', string)` gives me this output `<li>Item 3`

Comment: That's odd, it works for my string. You could add a '\1' to the replacement. Would you like me to add my string to show you it works?

Comment: No need to give me your string, when I do this:`print re.sub(r'</li>(\<br>)', '', '<li>Item 3</li><br>')` it gives me this: `<li>Item 3`

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to remove the `br` tags:

```
import re
print re.sub('<br>', "", '<li>Item 1</li><br>')
```

If there are many `br` tags in your document you have to store the data in a variable like this:

```
data = 'your full html document as a string'
print re.sub('<br>', "", data)
```

Then this will remove all the `br` tags in the entire `data` document.

If you only want to remove the `br` tags that are after the `li` tags then you can do it like this:

```
data = 'your full html document as a string'
print re.sub(r'^<li>\<br>', "", data)
```

Comment: There may be other `<br>` elements in the HTML which I don't want to remove as they are not straight after a list or image.

Comment: @PavSidhu ok I fix it one sec

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved without using regular expressions (insert reference to legendary regex/html answer here):

```
the_string = '<p>Text we want to keep</p><br>'
the_string = the_string.rstrip('<br>')
```